# Recursively search a directory for files whose content matches a regex and collect the paths of matching files in an array

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

```
$locations = Get-ChildItem $readLoc -recurse | ? {!$_.psiscontainer} | select-object name | %{$e = $_.name; get-content $e}

$array = @()

for($i = 0; $i -lt $locations.length; $i++){
    #if($locations.name[$i].length -eq "9"){
        $paths = Resolve-Path $locations.fullname[$i]
        $paths.path
        get-content $locations.name[$i]
        #$array += $paths.path 
    #}
}
```

I need to iterate through each file in the file system and open each file. I am checking to see if a string within the file matches a regular expression and then output the full path to that file into an array.

However, `$locations` isn't accepting the get-content.

get-content : Cannot find path

```
'C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\files\powershell\OWASP_ApplicationThreatModeling.docx'
because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:89
+ ... .psiscontainer} | select-object name |%{$e = $_.name; get-content $e}
+                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\p61782...atModeling.docx:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand.
```

Comment: Remove `|Select-Object Name  | %{$e = $_.name; get-content $e}` and then change it below to `get-content $locations[$i].fullname`. Or better yet, pass your `Get-ChildItem` to `Select-String` since it uses regex to match by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician) suggests, it's more efficient to use `Select-String` to perform the regex matching:

```powershell
$locations = Get-ChildItem $readLoc -File -Recurse |
               Select-String -List -Pattern '^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$' | 
                 Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
```

<sup>Note:

- The regex passed to `-Pattern` is a simplified version of the one [linked to in a comment](https://regex101.com/r/aaSeCG/1).

Note how the regex is enclosed in `'...'` rather than `"..."` so as to prevent inadvertent *up-front* interpretation of the string by PowerShell.</sup>

- `Get-ChildItem $readLoc -File -recurse` recursively enumerates all files in the target directory's subtree. Switch `-File` (along with its counterpart, `-Directory`) is available in PSv3+ and makes your `? {!$_.psiscontainer}` filter unnecessary.
- `Select-String` can operate on the *content* of files piped via `Get-ChildItem` and performs regex matching by default:

  - `-List` tells `Select-String` to only return the *first* match from each input file (if any).
- `Select-String` returns *match-information objects* whose `.Path` property contains the full path of the input file, so `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path` is used to output just the path of any file that contains at least 1 match.

Overall, variable `$locations` therefore receives the *array* of full paths of those files in which least 1 line matches the regex of interest.
Note that PowerShell automatically collects output from a command in an *array*, if the output comprises more than 1 element.

---

As for what you tried:

- Your immediate problem was that you passed `.Name` - i.e., a mere file *name* - to `Get-Content` rather than `.FullName`.
- Furthermore, your apparent intent was to collect *file-info objects* in array `$locations`, whereas your pipeline actually produced the *contents of all files* (as an array of lines).

Comment: yayyy... just got word that I have to now use this with .docx, .pdf, .xls and probably a few other file formats... Any clue?

Comment: @schnipdip: You should ask a _new_ question, but the short answer is that unless it's fine to read these files raw, as plain-text files - which may yield false positives - you'd need dedicated cmdlets that understand these file formats and can either search them directly or extract their plain-text contents for matching in PowerShell.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm thinking. There are readers out there that can read many file formats. So if I can get an API for it I think it will be okay. I wouldn't even know where to start to start to read other file formats from within powershell without utilizing a 3rd party application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the `FullName` property. Right now you're stripping that with your `Select-Object` command.

```
$locations = Get-ChildItem $readLoc -recurse | ? {!$_.psiscontainer}

for($i = 0; $i -lt $locations.length; $i++){
    $locations[$i].fullname
    get-content $locations[$i].fullname
}
```

Comment: I can get this to work, however when i use `for($i = 0; $i -lt $locations.length; $i++){
    $locations[$i].fullname
    $content = get-content $locations[$i].fullname
 if($content -match "^(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})|(\d{3}\d{2}\d{4})|(\d{3}\s{1}\d{2}\s{1}\d{4})$"){
  $array += $locations[$i].fullname
  $array` and try to append it to the array it doesn't do anything. On top of that it doesn't put anything into the array. There is a matching regex in a test file.

Comment: i added my version of your code in the updated section of the original post