# Searching for files with the same name and 3 letter extensions

Tags: powershell

So for my task i have to find all files on my C: partition that start with the word 'printer'and they have to have an extension that contains exactly 3 letters i also have to do the same for the .dll extension only

Comment: You should do a recursive file search with pattern matching. I think this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44552456/5350038

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. This forum is for ***solving issues with existing code***. It would be wise to attempt coding your idea. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then the fine people here can help work through any issues that arise.

Answer (score 0):

That is a lot of work for PowerShell (my old opinion). :)

If you do it in the native operating system it is:

```
dir printer*.??? /s /A-D
```

or

```
dir printer*.* /s /A-D
```

(In both cases from the root as /s denotes subfolders. You could add some other stuff for hidden files or folders but /? will give that to you. /A-D removes directories.)

You can pull that in to PowerShell with: cmd /r dir printer*.??? /s /A-D

Now if you do want to use PowerShell Natively you can read up but it'll be like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Include printer*.??? -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

You can swap out *.??? for *.dll in the code to get the results you want.

Comment: While the PowerShell command works as intended (and for interactive use could be shortened to `gci c:\ -include *.??? -r -file -ea silentlycontinue`), the `cmd.exe` `dir` command doesn't, because `printer*.???` will also match files with _fewer_ characters in the extension, such as `printer.ab`